# Unable to restore Database after dropping it in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I recently dropped my whole database from the application and tried to recreate it with a few day old backup. But I am unable to restore the dump as it is giving me the following error.

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'usermanagement.user' (errno: -1)
```

I know this is a foreign key issue, but how can this issue still persist if i have completely dropped all the database itself.

I actually didn't dropped the database using the mysql command but rather deleted the database folder from the mysql. Is there any way to restore the database successfully.

Comment: http://www.lenzg.net/archives/93-How-to-recover-accidentally-deleted-MySQL-database-files.html may be helpful to you

Comment: I think the case discussed here is different from mine. I tried it but still I am unable to create the user table and other mapping table related to it

Comment: That is the most brutal thing I have ever heard.

Comment: I've tried prettymuch everything upto now, including deleting all the constraint remotely similar to the current database i am trying to restore from the inforation schema table

Comment: restoring the dump to another schema name works the backup is fine, it is only on the same schema name that it is not working but I require the schema name so any help will be appreciated